# Sort vector by given requirement

Tags: r, sorting

In  `mv` , I want `z` at the first position ,the result as  `mv_sorted` .How to handle it ? Thanks!

```
mv <- c('w','t','z','f')

mv_sorted <- c('z','w','t','f')
```

Comment: Looking for `sort(mv, decreasing=TRUE)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `order`

```
> mv[order(mv != "z")]
[1] "z" "w" "t" "f"


> mv[order(mv == "z", decreasing = TRUE)]
[1] "z" "w" "t" "f"
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be :

```
first_vec <- c('z')
c(first_vec, setdiff(mv, first_vec))
#[1] "z" "w" "t" "f"
```

The benefit of this is you can have more than one element in `first_vec`

```
first_vec <- c('z', 'f')
c(first_vec, setdiff(mv, first_vec))
#[1] "z" "f" "w" "t"
```